# Is my mdadm RAID1 running?

Tags: mdadm, raid1, debian-buster

Sorry for the stupid question but I'm really confused.

**Is my RAID1 running and in a good health?**

```
lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Debian
Description:    Debian GNU/Linux 10 (buster)
Release:    10
Codename:   buster
root@trekto:~# uname -a
Linux trekto 4.19.0-9-amd64 #1 SMP Debian 4.19.118-2 (2020-04-29) x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

```
service mdadm status
● mdadm.service
   Loaded: masked (Reason: Unit mdadm.service is masked.)
   Active: inactive (dead)
```

Looks like **NOT running BUT**:

```
lsblk
NAME    MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE  MOUNTPOINT
sda       8:0    0 74.5G  0 disk  
├─sda1    8:1    0  953M  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0  952M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sda2    8:2    0 11.2G  0 part  
│ └─md1   9:1    0 11.2G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
└─sda3    8:3    0 62.4G  0 part  
  └─md2   9:2    0 62.4G  0 raid1 /
sdb       8:16   0 74.5G  0 disk  
├─sdb1    8:17   0  953M  0 part  
│ └─md0   9:0    0  952M  0 raid1 /boot
├─sdb2    8:18   0 11.2G  0 part  
│ └─md1   9:1    0 11.2G  0 raid1 [SWAP]
└─sdb3    8:19   0 62.4G  0 part  
  └─md2   9:2    0 62.4G  0 raid1 /
```

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid1] [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md0 : active raid1 sdb1[0] sda1[2]
      974848 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md2 : active raid1 sdb3[0] sda3[2]
      65421312 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

md1 : active (auto-read-only) raid1 sdb2[0] sda2[1]
      11709440 blocks super 1.2 [2/2] [UU]

unused devices: <none>
```

```
mdadm --detail /dev/md*
mdadm: /dev/md does not appear to be an md device
/dev/md0:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat May  9 22:34:20 2020
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 974848 (952.00 MiB 998.24 MB)
     Used Dev Size : 974848 (952.00 MiB 998.24 MB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Fri May 22 21:28:57 2020
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : trekto:0  (local to host trekto)
              UUID : 1fb0b10f:68dd1abe:07ace5bf:ce797ed8
            Events : 281

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       17        0      active sync   /dev/sdb1
       2       8        1        1      active sync   /dev/sda1
/dev/md1:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat May  9 22:34:39 2020
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 11709440 (11.17 GiB 11.99 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 11709440 (11.17 GiB 11.99 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Sat May  9 23:33:57 2020
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : trekto:1  (local to host trekto)
              UUID : cbdd415f:20b34ad6:1fe7991d:cb2c78e1
            Events : 34

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       18        0      active sync   /dev/sdb2
       1       8        2        1      active sync   /dev/sda2
/dev/md2:
           Version : 1.2
     Creation Time : Sat May  9 22:34:47 2020
        Raid Level : raid1
        Array Size : 65421312 (62.39 GiB 66.99 GB)
     Used Dev Size : 65421312 (62.39 GiB 66.99 GB)
      Raid Devices : 2
     Total Devices : 2
       Persistence : Superblock is persistent

       Update Time : Fri May 22 21:46:07 2020
             State : clean 
    Active Devices : 2
   Working Devices : 2
    Failed Devices : 0
     Spare Devices : 0

Consistency Policy : resync

              Name : trekto:2  (local to host trekto)
              UUID : d8bda655:d94cf675:5af758eb:f6d3a91b
            Events : 3199

    Number   Major   Minor   RaidDevice State
       0       8       19        0      active sync   /dev/sdb3
       2       8        3        1      active sync   /dev/sda3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, mdadm is running and shows as  in good health.

What is likely not working is the daemon monitoring the health which sends notifications of failure.